# How to use csv-parser to loop over rows in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-csv-parse

I am trying to write a script that will help me spit out boring code for work.

So at times, I get a .csv file that instructs me to create table fields, sometimes up to 50 at once! *(Using AL, a Business Central programming language.)*

**I tried writing this;**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const CreatesFile = fs.createWriteStream(path.resolve(__dirname, 'final.txt'), {
    flags: 'a' //flags: 'a' preserved old data
})

    fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(__dirname, 'AutomateVAR.csv'))
    .on('error', () => {
        // handle error
    })
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', (row) => {
        if (row["Var Type"] == "Text" || "Code") {
            CreatesFile.write( `field(; "${row["Var Name"]}"; ${row["Var Type"]}[${row["Var Length"]}]) {DataClassification = CustomerContent;} ` + '\r\n'); 
        }
         if (row["Var Type"] == "Boolean") {
            CreatesFile.write( `field(; "${row["Var Name"]}"; ${row["Var Type"]}) {DataClassification = CustomerContent;} ` + '\r\n');
        }
         if (row["Var Type"] == "Option")
        {
            CreatesFile.write( `field(; "${row["Var Name"]}"; ${row["Var Type"]}) { OptionMembers = ${row["Var Value"]};} ` + '\r\n');
        }
    })
    .on('end', () => {

    })
```

**and had this test .csv file;**

```
Var Name,Var Type,Var Value,Var Length
Customer,Code,,20
Employee,Text,,50
Cash Customer,Boolean,,
Car Type,Option,"""One"",""Two""",
```

The idea is to read the .csv file, loop through every row, and write to a text file which then I would just past in my code file I am working on. Sounds boring maybe but could save me tons of time. I am a noob Javascript/Node developer so pardon my shortcomings.

**After running the code, the output in text.txt is;**

```
field(; "Customer"; Code[20]) {DataClassification = CustomerContent;} 
field(; "Employee"; Text[50]) {DataClassification = CustomerContent;} 
field(; "Cash Customer"; Boolean[]) {DataClassification = CustomerContent;} 
field(; "Cash Customer"; Boolean) {DataClassification = CustomerContent;} 
field(; "Car Type"; Option[]) {DataClassification = CustomerContent;} 
field(; "Car Type"; Option) { OptionMembers = "One","Two";}
```

**Which is incorrect. The correct result should be;**

```
field(; "Customer"; Code[20]) {DataClassification = CustomerContent;} 
field(; "Employee"; Text[50]) {DataClassification = CustomerContent;} 
field(; "Cash Customer"; Boolean) {DataClassification = CustomerContent;} 
field(; "Car Type"; Option) { OptionMembers = "One","Two";}
```

**Guidance is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
if (row["Var Type"] == "Text" || "Code") {
```

Should be:

```
if (row["Var Type"] == "Text" || row["Var Type"] == "Code") {
```

Comment: That was quick and good! Thanks a ton! Mind telling me what was "Text" || "Code" evaluating to?

Comment: The right side of the || will always evaluate to true. E.g. `if ("Code")` will always be true.